# Arrange floating HTML element properly

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I am using the float to arrange the layout.

```
<style>
div {
    float: left;
}

.pro {
    width : 100px;
    color : blue;
}
</style>

<span>
<div class="pro">Long property name : </div>
<div>value</div>
</span>
```

When the "Long property name : " overflow to the new row, I want the "value" to go to new row too. What should I do in this HTML code ? Thanks. Right now the "value" still stay on top.

Current result

[image: Current result]

what  I want

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Okay, just learned to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better if you use `display: inline-block` instead of `float` for this:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /*For IE7*/
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wczcC/2/